# Notepad++: Remove lines between regular expressions

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ 6.x 
Is there a way to remove (in a non-greedy manner) any lines between two certain regular expressions? Something like sed '/a/,/b/d' 
edit: installing cygwin+sed did the job, but nevertheless, I'm curious if notepad++ can do this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine them into one regex, and then do a Replace with `. matches newline` enabled.

Search for `(prefix).*?(suffix)` and replace with `\1\2`.